# Sorting cells by distance

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sorting

So I'm trying to sort the cells by distance calculated. I have a struct

```
struct Sal {
var name:String
var coordinatesLat: CLLocationDegrees
var coordinatesLong: CLLocationDegrees
//var distance?
}
```

in scene A

```
func distanceFromLocation(location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance {

    // Find lat and long coordinates of current location
    let getLat = self.location.latitude
    let getLon = self.location.longitude
    let currentLocation =  CLLocation(latitude: getLat, longitude: getLon)
    // Calculate distance from current location to sal
    let distance = currentLocation.distanceFromLocation(location)
    return distance
}
```

scene B

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! SalCustomCell

    let name = sals[indexPath.row].name
    cell.name.text = name

    // Calculate distance between current location and sal
    let salLocation = CLLocation(latitude: sals[indexPath.row].coordinatesLat, longitude: sals[indexPath.row].coordinatesLong)

    // Display distance in cell.
    let distanceM = viewController.distanceFromLocation(salLocation)
    let distanceKm = round(distanceM/1000)
    cell.distance.text = String(distanceKm) + "km"
    return cell
}
```

I call the functions from scene A to display the distance in Km in scene B.  I'm trying to sort them by distance displayed in cell but i'm not to sure on how i would sort them by.  If it was name i could just do

```
sals.sortInPlace ({ $0.name < $1.name })
```

but I can't do

```
sals.sortInPlace ({ $0.distance < $1.distance })
```

because it's not apart of the struct. Do I need to make it apart of the struct? If so how?

I also tried to create an empty array and append the distance into the array to sort that way

```
var distance = [Double]()
self.distance.append(distanceKm) // inside cellForRowAtIndexPath
distance.sortInPlace ({ $0 < $1 })
```

But this didn't work out

Comment: You don't sort _cells_. You sort the _model data_ and reload the table view. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is _not_ the place to do this sorting; it must be done on the model data beforehand.

Comment: So i need to add the distance somehow to the struct and then sort it from my array that i've created, right? If that makes sense

Comment: You don't explain what `sals` is, but I assume it is an array of Sal. So then yes, you would simply sort that array. But you would not do this in `cellForRow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite Sal so that it contains your distance calculation function, like this:

```
struct Sal {
    var name:String
    var coordinatesLat: CLLocationDegrees
    var coordinatesLong: CLLocationDegrees
    func distanceFromLocation(location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now your array of Sal has a Sal feature that you can sort on.

Comment: I've been trying to implement it but I'm too sure how i would do it for me to be able to sort them by distance

Comment: I don't know what "by distance" means. By distance from _what_?

Comment: Suppose you mean distance from some common location `loc`. Then you would say `sals.sortInPlace{$0.distanceFromLocation(loc) < $1.distanceFromLocation(loc)}`

Comment: Then rewrite `distanceFromLocation` so that that is what it _does_. That's the whole point.

Comment: I think that's where I'm lost.  I don't understand how I would rewrite distanceFromLocation in the struct because its in scene A.  the struct is a separate swift file from scene A.  How would i rewrite it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "in scene A". My answer is that you should it put in the struct, _not_ "in scene A" (whatever you mean by that). Give a Sal the knowledge it needs to calculate its own distance from any given location. Done.

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out but i simply can't get my head around it. What am I meant to write inside the braces of distanceFromLocation? When i talk about scene A, I'm referring to a ViewController file.  The struct Sal is in a separate swift file from both scene A and scene B(Also a separate ViewController file), if that makes sense.